# Как сохранять информацию о позиции нажатого элемента в recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, android-shared-preferences

как можно сохранить информацию о позиции нажатого элемента recyclerview. Мне нужно выделять нажатый элемент recyclerview и сохранять это выделение после перезахода. Пытался это сделать по типу  создания booleanArray и по нажатию на элемент изменять значение на true. Но как можно сохранить этот массив, чтобы после перезахода значения не сбрасывались.

Адаптор

```
class UsersAdapter(private val videoTitles: List<String>,
               private val Trening: List<String>,
               private val clickListener: onClickRecyclerViewItem,
               private val array: BooleanArray
               ): RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, parent, false)
    return CustomViewHolder(cellForRow)
}


@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val videoTitle = videoTitles[position]
    val Trening1 = Trening[position]
    holder.view.name.text= videoTitle
    holder.view.quantity.text= Trening1
    holder.view.setOnClickListener {
        clickListener.onClickItemListener()
        array[position] = true}
    }

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return videoTitles.size
}



@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
class CustomViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
}
}
```

Comment: в адаптер передавать список объектов с полем isSelected и менять его при нажатии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучший способ в этом случае использовать `ViewModel` на которую будет подписана вью. При нажатии на айтем мы будем перезаписывать значение и сохранять в `SharedPreferences`

[image: ezgif-com-gif-maker.gif]

Вот рабочий пример который я накидал чтобы была ясна логика.

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        MainViewModelFactory(PreferenceManager(this))
    ).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.items.observe(this) {
        recycler_view.adapter = MainAdapter(it) { selected, item ->
            viewModel.changeItem(item, selected)
        }
    }
}
}
```

MainAdapter:

```
class MainAdapter(
private val items: MutableList<Item>,
private val clickListener: (Boolean, Item) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.MainViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = MainViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false)
)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = items[position]
    with(holder) {
        title.text = item.title
        itemView.background = getDrawable(
            itemView.context,
            if (item.isSelected) R.color.purple_500 else R.color.black
        )

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener(!item.isSelected, item)
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

class MainViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val title: TextView = view.title
}
}
```

MainViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel(private val manager: PreferenceManager) : ViewModel() {

val items = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        var savedItems = manager.getItems()
        if (savedItems.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            manager.saveItems(
                mutableListOf(
                    Item(1, "Первый", false),
                    Item(2, "Второй", false),
                    Item(3, "Третий", false),
                    Item(4, "Четвертый", false),
                    Item(5, "Пятый", false)
                )
            )
            savedItems = manager.getItems()
        }
        items.postValue(savedItems)
    }
}

fun changeItem(item: Item, isSelected: Boolean) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val newItems = mutableListOf<Item>()
        items.value?.map {
            when (it.id) {
                item.id -> newItems.add(Item(item.id, item.title, isSelected))
                else -> newItems.add(it)
            }
        }
        items.postValue(newItems)
        manager.saveItems(newItems)
    }
}
}
```

MainViewModelFactory:

```
class MainViewModelFactory(private val manager: PreferenceManager) :
ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {

override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return MainViewModel(manager) as T
}
}
```

PreferenceManager:

```
class PreferenceManager(context: Context) {

private val gson = Gson()
private val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MAIN_STORAGE", MODE_PRIVATE)

fun saveItems(items: MutableList<Item>) {
    val json = gson.toJson(items)
    prefs.edit().putString("items", json).apply()
}

fun getItems(): MutableList<Item>? {
    val type = object : TypeToken<MutableList<Item>>() {}.type
    val json = prefs.getString("items", "")

    return gson.fromJson(json, type)
}
}
```

Item:

```
data class Item(
val id: Int,
val title: String,
var isSelected: Boolean
)
```

Доп. зависимости:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант вы можете создать некоторую UI Model в которой будет хранится флаг и данные.

```
class UiModel(
    val videoTitle: String,
    val trening: String,
    val isChecked: Boolean
)
```

На моменте создания списка вы создаете список таких вот моделей. Изначально в каждой из модели `isChecked = false`. Когда вы выбираете элемент вы меняете в модели этот флаг на `true` и сохраняете измененный список. Куда его хранить это уже детали вашей реализации. Самый очевидный способ это база данных, но он не единственный. После того как вы перезаходите - вы просто грузите этот список и задаете ему значения согласно уже сохраненных флагов.